# Separate DNS server for subdomain.example.com

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, dns-servers

I have a website which has the address: `subdomain.example.com`.

I would like to know if it can have its own DNS server like Route 53 (NS records, CNAME, A, etc.) or it is tied to the `example.com`?

Comment: Why do you want this? Understanding your needs can help us provide more useful answers.

Comment: Actually, the subdomain is pointing to an ec2 instance having elastic ip . and the domain is hosted on some classic hosting compny . I would like to migrate the subdomain to route 53 in order to be able to have a full controll and also want to use an ELB .

Comment: You could move the whole domain to a better DNS server, then point the root A/MX records to the old server IP.

Comment: It is not possible unfortunately to move the whole domain . but here it is saying it is possible but i do not know how   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingSubdomain.html#GetParentDomainResourceRecords

Answer (score 3):

It's a complicated answer if it's explained clearly. The domain's DNS will have to point the subdomain to the IP of the subdomain's DNS server (new DNS server explicitly for subdomain).

If you require a simple answer, yes. Absolutely. You can have another DNS server. No problems. You should explicitly specify in the DNS of the domain to point this subdomain to the new server or use the DNS that comes free with the domain.